# How do I make the event triggered by a key only happen once?

Tags: java, keyboard

Disclaimer: I'm really new at this and I apologize in advance if: 
1) my question has already been asked (I've tried searching and had a lot of trouble finding what I needed) 
or 2) if I'm not asking the question correctly.

Basically, I'm trying to make a game where pressing the spacebar triggers a sort of "super-power" that will perform a set of actions just once. Afterwards, if they try to press it again, it'll run up some sort of dialogue box that says their one-time super-power has already been used.

What I have:

```
       try { 

            Key move = canvas.getLastKey();
            int space = 0;

            if(move == Key.SPACE) {
                if (space == 0) {
                    space = 1;
                }
                if (space == 2){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "superpower already used");
                }
            }



            if( space == 1 ) {
                //action here

                canvas.resetKey(); 
                space = 2; 
            }
       }
```

Right now, the super-hero action is on an endless loop but if I reset the key here:

```
            if(move == Key.SPACE) {
                if (space == 0) {
                    space = 1;
                    canvas.resetKey();
                }
```

the user can just use the super-power over and over again. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the third line, you have written `int space=0` so your variable is constantly reset to 0...
You have to initialize it elsewhere (the beginning of your program is a good place for any global variable).

Comment: thanks! after doing that and sticking " move = null; " for when space = 2 everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider moving int space = 0, outside of the try block. I suppose your try block gets invoked repeatedly, so you should declare this variable under a global scope.